# Ids generating strategy for Hibernate Table per Concrete class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have read some questions on this site and still haven't really found the answer for my questions, so bear with me.

I **have** to use the `TABLE_PER_CONCRETE_CLASS` Strategy for my inheritance Mapping on an **existing database**( i dont have another choice ) and had some problems while trying to persist new objects. Afterwards i learned that for this strategy i will have to use  `GenerationType.Table` and i dont really know how its used. Three questions:

1. Imagine each subclasses have their owns tables and therefore different sequence of ids. How could i realize that with `GenerationType.Table`, as i have learnt that this strategy make ALL the subclasses have ONE sequence of IDs.
2. How should i set up `@TableGenerator`, i know that with this annotation a new table will be created and stores the next avaiable ids. But at first it seems like the new table doesnt know what the initially next available id is like, should i set it up manually?
3. Should i use assigned identifiers ? Can i retrieve it with `@Formula` ?

Comment: *Imagin each subclasses have their owns tables and therefore different sequence of ids*: that's your mistake. If a Student and a Teacher **are** both instances of the super-entity Person, they must share the same sequance of IDs: you need to be able, from an ID, to uniquely identify a Person. If they should both have their own sequence of IDs, then Person shouldn't be an entity, and you shouldn't use entity inheritance.

Comment: @JBNizet hi, still i have an inheritance here to implement (say i have to map a List of Persons, including Teachers and Students) and the database was created years ago, so there isnt anything i could do about that. How can i solve the case without changing the database very much, is MappedSupperClass  a solution ?

Comment: If there is a teacher with the same ID as a student, then they must be two separate entities. You can use MappedSuperclass to share code, butyou can't have an association to a Person.